# Get a single, matching row from a .csv without searching twice?

Tags: performance, search, powershell, csv, powershell-3.0

I was wondering if there was a better way I can grab a single row matching a specific query, without searching twice.
In my code originally, I wanted to count how many rows in my .CSV matched my search query.

```
$raisins=($table | ? {$_.'fruit' -like '*grapes*' -and $_.'hours in sunlight' -like '*a lot*'}| measure).Count
```

Now, I'm tasked with taking a single row from those same search query results.

```
$raisinHit=($table | ? {$_.'fruit' -like '*grapes*' -and $_.'hours in sunlight' -like '*a lot*})
$raisinHit=$raisinHit[0]
```

However, I find it really inefficient that I have to search through my .CSV using the same query from earlier, just to find a single result I had already glossed over. 
Is there a better way to do this? If so, can you explain how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign the matches to a variable, then return the count and an element from the variable.

```
$raisins = @($table | 
     ? {$_.'fruit' -like '*grapes*' -and $_.'hours in sunlight' -like '*a lot*'})

$raisins.count
$raisins[0]
```

The `@()` around the pipeline ensures that `$raisins` will be an array, even if only one match is returned.